# South African to apply for Dutch citizenship

Tags: citizenship, netherlands

My son is 17 years old this year. Both his father's parents were Dutch and lived in Hengelo. They immigrated to South Africa in the 1950s. Does Dutch law allow him to apply for citizenship?

Comment: Were the parents of his father  Dutch citizens by birth or they were naturalized? And if they were naturalized was that before his father was born or after?

Comment: It depends on whether the father was Dutch at his birth, which he probably was, and whether he lost that nationality before your son was born. When was your son's father born? Also were you married at the time of your son's birth?

Comment: Also significant: Did your son's grandparents naturalize in South Africa?  If so, was it before or after your son's father was born?  The answers to these questions will help determine whether your son's father was born a Dutch citizen.